# ss and netstat show different multicast groups

Tags: multicast, netstat, ss

On one of my systems at work good ol' netstat shows multicast group membership information, and ss is missing a couple. I wonder why. For example:

```
[root@myhost ~]# netstat -gn | egrep "Inter|239.192"
Interface       RefCnt Group  
em4.204         1      239.192.33.183
em1.16          2      239.192.35.1
em1.16          2      239.192.12.98
em1.16          1      239.192.32.1


[root@myhost ~]# ss -apu | egrep "State|239.192"
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port                 Peer Address:Port                
UNCONN     0      0      239.192.35.1:12965                    *:*                    
UNCONN     0      0      239.192.12.98:12965                    *:*                    
UNCONN     0      0      239.192.35.1:12965                    *:*                    
UNCONN     0      0      239.192.12.98:12965                    *:*
```

Notice that ss shows only those groups with a RefCnt of 2.

Technically, `ip maddr show` is the replacement for `netstat -gn` but it doesn't include the RefCnt, and its output is more cumbersome. Also, we're interested in the more detailed output of ss which can include the PID of the listening processes (not seen here because no processes are actually currently listening to the multicast, as show by `netstat -ulpn`:

```
[root@myhost ~]# netstat -ulpn | egrep "Proto|239.192"
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 239.192.35.1:12965      0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp     4480      0 239.192.12.98:12965     0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 239.192.35.1:12965      0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 239.192.12.98:12965     0.0.0.0:*                           -
```